# Vscode não reconhece modulos externas em Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Estou usando o vscode para aprender python porque achei mais agradável, porém quando tento importar bibliotecas do pypi.org depois de te baixado as mesmas o VSCODE aponta que não existe módulo com aquele nome a ser importado. Caso eu digite pip install pydf (exemplo de modulo que eu tenho instalado) pelo console do VSCODE ele aponta que já está instalado. Se eu for na pasta da minha virtualEnv o arquivo do pydf está lá, mas na hora de rodar o código dá erro, oq fazer?

Edit1: Caso eu rode o mesmo script usando a mesma virtualEnv pelo Pycharm funciona normalmente, mas estou usando o VSCODE devido a facilidade de integrar com o github desktop

Comment: Verifica se a versão do python no VSCode eh a mesma que a versão do python que está instalando as bibliotecas. As vezes no seu prompt vc está mexendo com python 2.7 e no VSCode o python 3.7, e o computador está dando preferencia pra versão 2.7

Comment: Para descobrir isso, no canto inferior direito do VSCode mostra a versão do python que ele está usando. Para descobrir a versão que vc está usando para instalar as bibliotecas, no prompt (como adm) escreve python, logo vc vai entrar o terminal do python e vai mostrar a versão que está usando

Comment: Recomendo utilizar algo mais simples para aprender. Como o próprio idle que vem com o python. Caso tenha interesse, o anaconda é uma ótima alternativa de plataforma para configurar ambientes com o conda e instalar as dependências que precisar. Inclusive existe um plugin no vscode do anaconda para selecionar o ambiente em que quer trabalhar e muito mais.

Comment: Na sua jornada voce esta usando algum ambiente virtual ou apenas o python standart a versão 3.9.. ?

Answer (score -3):

**Verifique se antes do diretório no terminal do próprio VSCode tá com o nome do ambiente virtual que você criou, se não é porque você está tentando rodar módulos que estão la dentro sem estar rodando seu script dentro do ambiente. No ubunto eu uso o seguinte comando no terminal:source DiretorioDoSeuAmbienteVirtual/bin/activate. Caso esteja usando windows de uma pesquisada que o comando é diferente eu creio.**